# how to add element to previous element(append) using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have following code in jquery :

```
var qtype ="<select id='qtype'><option>qt1 </option><option>qt2</option></select>";
var abc ="<select id='t1'><option>Simple 1</option><option>Simple 2</option></select>";
var xyz ="<select id='t2'><option>Hard</option></select>";
var pqr ="<select id='t3'><option>Diff</option></select>";

$("#qttype").html(qtype);
var qtype=$("qttype"); 
if(qtype== "qt1"){
 $("#t1").change(function(){        
    $("#abc").change(function(){
     $("#divid").html(abc+xyz);
         $("#divid").html(abc+xyz+pqr);

 });  }
```

but it does not properly append element i mean when i change "simple 1" this shows second combo box with "xyz" but when I again click it show me double appended element i want to display only once when i change the combobox values.

Comment: If you want to append then you need to use, for example, `.append(abc+xyz)`. The `.html()` function you're using *replaces* the existing content.

Comment: @AndrewPeacock: to be fair to our OP, there's really only one other question with a good answer for them to accept -- one's about to be closed and the others don't have any answers with upvotes.

Comment: @Cory Just an automatic reaction =/ Tend to not investigate much. But `.append()` will fix the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you got the element located after the position you want append, you should take a look on [.before()](http://api.jquery.com/before/). You can use the [.after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/) too, although in this case you must select the previous element.

- Example:

  ```
  $("element").before("<p>this p will be added before the 'element'</p>");
  $("element").after(" <p>this p will be added after  the 'element'</p>");
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Made one example, hope this will help!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document.body).append('<div id="abc"></div>'); // create new #abc and append it directly to body
    $('#abc').append($('<div/>').attr('id','divid').html('hello!'));
    var course = $('<select id="qtype"></select>'); // jquery object containing #qtype
    var abc = '<option value="s">Simple</option>'; // string
    var xyz = '<option value="h">Hard</option>'; // string
    var pqr = '<option value="d">Diff</option>'; // string
    course.append(abc).append(xyz).append(pqr); // triple call of .append()
    //alert("course is " + course + ",\n course[0] is " + course[0] + ' ~ ' + course[0].innerHTML);
    $('#abc').before(course); //insert <select> before #abc
    $('#qtype').change(function(){
        var str = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
        str += ' ~ ' + this.options[this.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
        $('#abc').html(str);
    });
});
```

Example @ [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YGkvs/), more details at [jquery website](http://api.jquery.com/category/attributes/)